# Anomaly in print statement in python

Tags: python

Suppose I have a `print` statement in python as given :

```
print "components required to explain 50% variance : %d" % (count)
```

This statement gives a `ValuError`, but if I have this `print` statement :

```
print "components required to explain 50% variance"
```

Why does this happen ?

Comment: `print "components required to explain 50%% variance : %d" % (count)`

Comment: `.format` is more sophisticated, just a heads up

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message is pretty helpful here:

```
>>> count = 10
>>> print "components required to explain 50% variance : %d" % (count)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: unsupported format character 'v' (0x76) at index 35
```

So python sees `% v` and it thinks that it is a format code.  However, `v` isn't a supported format character so it raises an error.

The *fix* is obvious once you know it -- You need to escape the `%`s that aren't part of a format code.  How do you do that?  By adding another `%`:

```
>>> print "components required to explain 50%% variance : %d" % (count)
components required to explain 50% variance : 10
```

Note that you could also use `.format` which is more convenient and powerful in a lot of circumstances:

```
>>> print "components required to explain 50% variance : {:d}".format(count)
components required to explain 50% variance : 10
```

Answer (score 4):

The `%` operator, applied to strings, performs a substitution for every '%' in the string. '50%' does not specify a valid substitution; to simply include a percent sign in the string, you have to double it.